# Wiring under cabinet range hood to a power cord

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m trying to install an under the cabinet range hood to a power cord. Our old hood had a power cord attached so there is no electric wiring to attach it to. The instructions don’t have much to go by it’s a Broan model BCS330WWC hood (Canadian model) and I’ve purchased an appliance replacement cord 15amp and 125 volts. I’m going to connect the wiring from the hood to the power cord.  From what I can tell from the website it has been rated for 15 amp and 120 VAC. Are these compatible or am I going to have too much power coming from the power cord and start a fire? Thanks for your help

Comment: you can't use flexible cord to connect a range hood, NEC 400.7/8,  unless Canada code is greatly more liberal than US code (I doubt it). I would use armored cable, and replace the receptacle with a ”cover plate with a knockout in it.”

Comment: You could use NM though and put a plug on the end of it, right? You would use a 1-gang box either inset in the wall board or surface mounted and put a receptacle in it. On mine I put a switch in the box, but I think a plug and receptacle would have been better. I don't think there is any legal way to splice a cord to the house wiring or could you use wire nuts in a box?